# How is soliciting a prostitute illegal in states where prostitution is legal?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, discrimination

This question is not concerned with whether prostitution should be legal or not. It is also not concerned with the moral implications of either position.

What I find hard to accept is in states where prostitution is legal, soliciting a prostitute still gets you on a register of sex offenders.

You can pay money for sex in Nevada: You just have to have the prostitute infer your desire for the service from deductive reasoning alone.

I don't get the logic of how a service can be legal but asking for it is not.

If soliciting a prostitute is a problem then prostitution should be illegal.

To me both should be illegal or legal together.

Comment: This seems very confused, is not focused or clear and I cannot distinguish the "indignant rant" part from an actual, answerable question in StackExchange format.  You have 1715 rep, I assume you know how this works?

Comment: Ok I have made an edit

Comment: Prostitutes do advertise their services don't they? No inferences required.

Comment: @Greendrake some advertisements for sexual services rely heavily on implication and therefore require inference.  I imagine that such advertisements are more common in places where prostitution is illegal, however.  I also wonder whether "solicit" is defined such that even responding to an explicit advertisement might count as solicitation.

Comment: What the prostitute does, and what his or her client/customer does are not the same thing. It is quite conceivable that the law makes one punishable but not the other, and it is quite conceivable that different countries or states disagree which one should be illegal. Mostly depends on whether they look at the prostitute as a victim or a perpetrator. Quite similar, selling drugs and using drugs are legally very different.

Comment: Something to consider with your Nevada example is the question of legal versus illegal depends on where it is happening as from what I understand it is only legal in certain counties and places of business. Outside of those it is still illegal for all parties involved.

Comment: @JoeW indeed; see [user6726's answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/78030/333).

Answer (score 6):

Focusing on the titular question, **it's not**. Soliciting prostitution is not illegal in exactly those places where it is legal to engage in prostitution. [Here's the law.](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/nrs-201.html#NRS201Sec295) NRS 201.354(1) says

> It is unlawful for any person to engage in prostitution or
> solicitation therefor, *except in a licensed house of prostitution*.

FYI, street prostitution is not legal in Nevada, or anywhere else in the US. This is not to be confused with the situation in jurisdictions which shifted the onus of illegality onto the customer as opposed to the service-provider.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the law is under no obligation to be "reasonable". Second, many people consider hiring someone to engage in prostitution to be victimizing that person. To those people, it makes perfect sense that being victimized is not a crime, but victimizing is. For instance, it's not a crime for a minor to have sex with an adult (that is, it's not a crime on the minor's side), but it is illegal for the adult to solicit sex from the minor. It's not illegal for a black person to offer to work for less than a white person, but it is illegal for an employer to offer less money to black people. It's not illegal to work for less than minimum wage, but it is illegal to offer less than minimum wage. It's not illegal to get legal advice from a nonlawyer, but it is illegal to practice law if you're not a lawyer. It's not illegal to buy food from a restaurant that doesn't follow food safety laws, but it is illegal to serve food in violation of food safety laws.  Do you see a contradiction in laws that make hiring a minor for prostitution a crime, but absolve the minor of any criminal liability? You may not think that prostitution is in the same category, but obviously other people do.

Comment: "many people consider hiring someone to engage in prostitution to be victimizing that person": this seems to be the key.  To "many people" we might add "...and some legislatures..." or "...and some criminal codes...."

Answer (score 4):

### Because it reduces prostitution without criminalising sex workers

For example, under the [Nordic model of prostitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_model_approach_to_prostitution), everything the client does is illegal and everything the sex worker does is legal. This attacks the demand side of the problem by making procuring a sex act risky thus disincentivising people looking to buy but it doesn’t make the sex workers, who are often vulnerable people, criminals.

That’s the logic of it.

As to how it is enforced, police charge the buyer and say "good evening" to the seller.

Comment: Once more, with specificity: this answers "why," but does not address the logical question of "how" -- not "how is it enforced," but "how is it logically possible for a consensual transaction between two participants to result in criminal liability for one participant and not the other."

Comment: @phoog the obvious answer is that the law does not have to follow that sort of logic.

Comment: @phoog That strikes me as not really illogical at all. For example, you'ld have to be very far on the libertarian side to think that selling dangerously substandard goods at low prices to the poor and desperate shouldn't be criminalised. Admittedly, it is more common to criminalise the seller than the customer but as User65535 said, the law doesn't have to follow some abstract principle of symmetry.

Comment: @phoog I don’t understand your objection - there are plenty of laws that do this. Sanctions, for example, criminalise the actions of the person in the sanctioning state but not the person in the sanctioned state.